# JPA association between three entities with specific business requirements

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm making an application that has three entities: DomesticViolence, Person and  PersonState.

I'm new in JPA and i have no idea how to map these three entities while respecting the following business requirements:The DomesticViolence can own many people. One person can  have  many DomesticViolences. Each association
between  DomesticViolence and a Person has many PersonStates (drunk, drugged, sober, etc.).  I made the following associations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "domestic_violence")
@Getter
@Setter
public class DomesticViolence {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "domestic-violence-person",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "domestic-violence-id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person-id")
     )
     private Set<Person> peopele;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Person {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "peopele")
    private Set<DomesticViolence> domesticViolence;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
     private Set<PersonState> personState;
}
 
@Entity
@Table(name = "person-state")
@Getter
@Setter
public class PersonState {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "domestic_violence_id")
    private DomesticViolence domesticViolence;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;
}
```

But i think this is not the right reletionship between these three entities.
I'm sorry if i have repetitive question, but i couldn't find answer related to my business requirements.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Questions about "Best Practices" or soliciting opinions in general are considered off topic. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265928/is-a-best-practice-question-off-topic

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I have already corrected my post and i have added my example code.